# How to add files to an asset that has its $sourcePath in the vendor directory in Yii2?

Tags: assets, yii2

I'm making an asset bundle based on a JS plugin (DataTables) that has been installed through composer in the `vendor/` directory. The asset bundle class file looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace app\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class DatatablesAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $sourcePath = '@vendor/datatables/datatables/media';

    public $css = [
        'css/jquery.dataTables.min.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
        'js/jquery.dataTables.js',
    ];
    public $publishOptions = [
        'forceCopy' => true,
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
    ];
}
```

This works fine. The files are copied from the vendor directory and are being published to the `web/assets/[hash]` directory.

However, I would like to use a CSS file to style the datatables plugin further, but still would like to use the images included in the base plugin for this. As I do not know the `[hash]` of the directory being published into the `assets` directory I cannot access these images, how do I solve this?

- Can I add a CSS file from outside the $sourcePath to the `assets/[hash]` directory? Then I can use a relative path (like the plugin itself also does). This sounds like the most elegant solution.
- Can I somehow know the `[hash]` and reference this in my custom CSS file?

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="<?=Yii::$app->assetManager->getPublishedUrl('@vendor/xxxx/yyyyy/assets')?>/xxx/yyy/fav.ico">
```

Or if the package has a alias of it's own you can use

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="<?=Yii::$app->assetManager->getPublishedUrl('@pachageName/assets')?>/xxx/yyy/fav.ico">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the bundle object to get the path with the hash and append relative paths of files in the asset folder.

The asset gets [registered](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-view#registerAssetBundle()-detail) somewhere (`$this` is the view object):

```
$asset = $this->registerAssetBundle(DatatablesAsset::class);
// or alternatively
$asset = DatatablesAsset::register($this);
```

In a view file you can then use the [base url](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-assetbundle#$baseUrl-detail) (hash included)

```
<img src="<?= $asset->baseUrl . '/images/image.jpg' ?>">
```

> The **base URL** for the relative asset files listed in $js and $css.
>
> If $sourcePath is set, this property will be overwritten by
>   yii\web\AssetManager when it publishes the asset files from
>   $sourcePath.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But, the exact question was how to use those images in CSS files, i.e. as background-image. It's a bit of a tricky business to do this elegantly.

Comment: @PaulvanSchayck I see. At least it is one way to get and create the path. I'll leave the answer, since it may help others with anything like that.